# Crop image captured with camera session

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, crop

I am trying to crop image captured with camera session with specific rect of interest. For find proportional crop rect I am using `previewLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted` method. But after cropping i got wrong ratio.

Debug example:

```
(lldb) po rectOfInterest.width / rectOfInterest.height
0.7941176470588235

(lldb) po image.size.width / image.size.height
0.75

(lldb) po outputRect.width / outputRect.height
0.9444444444444444

(lldb) po Double(cropped.width) / Double(cropped.height)
0.7080152671755725
```

[image: Debug]

As you can see, I am expecting that cropped image ratio will be `~0.79` as `rectOfInterest` which I am using for cropping.

Method:

```
private func makeImageCroppedToRectOfInterest(from image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let previewLayer = cameraController.previewLayer
    let rectOfInterest = layoutLayer.layoutRect

    let outputRect = previewLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: rectOfInterest)

    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return image
    }

    let width = CGFloat(cgImage.width)
    let height = CGFloat(cgImage.height)

    let cropRect = CGRect(x: outputRect.origin.x * width,
                          y: outputRect.origin.y * height ,
                          width: outputRect.size.width * width,
                          height: outputRect.size.height * height)

    guard let cropped = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) else {
        return image
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cropped, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
}
```

Target rect: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I think you misinterpreted the `metadataOutputRectConverted` method usage.
There is no way your code could return a cropped image with the same aspect ratio since you are multiplying (what I think are) *virtually unrelated numbers* one to each other.

You can try this method

```
previewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
```

To get an idea on what the actual calculations made from the `metadataOututRectConverted` are.

I think you could explain better what you want to achieve, and maybe provide a sample project (or at the very least some more context on what are the actual images/rects you are using) to help us debug, if you want to have more help on this.

Comment: I have `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` which shows camera capture area, additionally I have "target" rect inside camera preview layer which smaller than rect of camera preview layer. In result i want to get exactly the same picture, which user see in my "target rect"

Comment: I’ll try something later, in the meantime could you provide a sample project?

Comment: I added screenshot of my camera preview layer. As you can see I have actual camera capture rect (dark area), and I have target rect (light area).

Comment: `previewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))`  not suitable as I have no data about metadata output rect

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hUqVGKDaxsxxKcS-MNsn7FVnVpC4ekGh

Comment: What do you mean with no data? You can pass that rect to get some info on the actual size. A rect like that (0,0,1,1) should return the whole rect after the conversion..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Enricoza I understand how to fix my problem. Here is code:

```
private func makeImageCroppedToRectOfInterest(from image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let previewLayer = cameraController.previewLayer
        let rectOfInterest = layoutLayer.layoutRect

        let metadataOutputRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        let outputRect = previewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: metadataOutputRect)

        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return image
        }

        let width = image.size.width
        let height = image.size.height

        let factorX = width / outputRect.width
        let factorY = height / outputRect.height
        let factor = max(factorX, factorY)

        let cropRect = CGRect(x: (rectOfInterest.origin.x - outputRect.origin.x) * factor,
                              y: (rectOfInterest.origin.y - outputRect.origin.y) * factor,
                              width: rectOfInterest.size.width * factor,
                              height: rectOfInterest.size.height * factor)

        guard let cropped = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) else {
            return image
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: cropped, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    }
```

Comment: This code crops captured image, where:
1. `rectOfInterest` – your rect which you want to keep in result image
2. `outputRect` – ACTUAL capturing rect (it's not what you see on the screen)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this actually works on every rect, but if you say so I trust you :D

Comment: The Y of the cropRect is not computed correctly. However, X is.
My cropped image seems to be cropped correctly horizontally but not vertically!